# python + check value in key in long dictionary

Tags: linux, python3

we have the following API that get results in to `res` , and  `res` is type of dictionary

```
  res = api_req.ambari_request("/api/v1/clusters/HDP/host_components?HostRoles/component_name=NAMENODE&metrics/dfs/FSNamesystem/HAState=active")
```

and `res` dictionary looks like this:

.
.

```
    "display_name": "NameNode",
    "init_count": 0,
    "install_failed_count": 0,
    "installed_count": 0,
    "recovery_enabled": "true",
    "repository_state": "CURRENT",
    "service_name": "HDFS",
    "started_count": 2,
    "state": "STARTED",
    "total_count": 2,
    "unknown_count": 0
},
```

we need to verify that all `started_count` are equal to `2` in the dictionary

appreciate to get the right approach for this test

Comment: Python dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys, what do you mean "all" started_count?

Answer (score 0):

python dictionaries values can be accessed with the subscript operator [] given a string which is the key corresponding to the value you wish to acquire. this gets the value associated with the "started_count" key.

```py
api_data = {
    "display_name": "NameNode",
    "init_count": 0,
    "install_failed_count": 0,
    "installed_count": 0,
    "recovery_enabled": "true",
    "repository_state": "CURRENT",
    "service_name": "HDFS",
    "started_count": 2,
    "state": "STARTED",
    "total_count": 2,
    "unknown_count": 0
}      

if api_data["started_count"] == 2:
    print("started_count is 2")
else:
    print("started_count is not 2")
```